# AWS EC2 instance works with thousands of http calls simultaneously

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created a JSP page. When ever i send HTTP request to this page i create a EC2 instance on AWS and send back the Public IP in response but it takes atleast 10 sec to send response back.

I want to test 1000 HTTP calls simultaneously which means 1000 EC2 instances will initialize in AWS.

How can i test it? How can i generate 1000 Request to this page and then get the response back?

Comment: Fire off thousands of calls and see what happens? This is for programming questions, not server load testing.

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools for simulating traffic. An example of this is [Apache's Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). It takes some setting up but once you have it set up, you can send as many http requests as the machine sending them can handle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It's really helpful.

Comment: I want to know one for thing. i want to add cloudwatch on my autoscaling group.When traffic increase number of instance increases automatically and when traffic decrease it automatically decrease instance. So where should i have to create alarm?On load balancer or autoscaling group and which metrics should be used to handle this scenario.

Comment: Should you be interested, you'll find http://www.connectria.com/blog/aws-auto-scaling/ to be an interesting read. It recommends you put the thresholds(alarms) on the load balancer since this is the main interface to your application.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple test, you can use something like siege.  There's also an AWS-based solution called "bees with machineguns" which can distribute the load across multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use some kind of load testing tool to achieve this. I will suggest Jmeter. You can also read this useful blog on doing the same.

http://vdaubry.github.io/2015/02/24/Distributed-load-testing-with-jmeter-and-EC2/